# Variable lengthed array in gcc

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

I'm a beginning C++ programmer. So, I just learned that gcc has an extension that allows variably sized array without having to dynamically allocate memory. I want to know if this variably sized array is allocated in the stack or heap.

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually it's allocated with automatic storage duration, so in terms of implementation, you can *think* of it as being on the stack.

Do consider using `std::vector` as an alternative though as that's standard and therefore portable C++.

Comment: It's vector dynamic? I've heard that vector is comparatively slower

Comment: @SuryaK That's premature optimization. Don't do that. `std::vector` is blazingly fast. If you think not, benchmark it, then come back. Stick to using `std::vector` now.

Comment: @SuryaK _"I've heard that vector is comparatively slower"_ Not significantly if used right. Make use of the initial allocation count, or use `reserve()`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable sized array is allocated in the stack.

Comment: So, it means it is a bad idea to use VLAs to hold large data and better to use dynamically allocated array or std::vector. Right?

Comment: I'd recommend dynamically allocated array over VLAs

Answer (score 0):

VLA's are not supported by the C++ standard, although some compilers such as GCC do have them as an extension.

std::vector <> VLA in the GCC implementation.

- std::vector is resizable and allocates memory on the heap.
- VLA is not resizable, is limited by the maximum stack size and doesn't allocate memory.

So there is a flexibility difference, and there can be a performance difference especially if the array creation happens regularly (such as in a tight loop).

That said, some of these differences can sometimes be mitigated by for example, moving the 'array' outside of loops etc